# Filtering elements in mongodb collection with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, nosql

I want to get all children names that are **female** in a collection in mongodb using `ruby`:

The elements in the collection are like this:

```
 [
 { "name" => "John",
   "children" => [{"genre" => "male", "name" => "Rick"},
                  {"genre" => "female", "name" => "Mary"}
                 ]
 },
 { "name" => "Richard",
   "children" => [{"genre" => "female", "name" => "Vicky"},
                  {"genre" => "female", "name" => "Mary"}
                 ]
 }]
```

When I execute:

```
collection.find({"children" => {"genre" => "female"}})
```

I get a `Mongo::OperationTimeout: Timed out waiting on socket read.`

Moreover, I don't want the list of all parents, but only the list of different female children.

If I use pure ruby, I could do this with:

```
collection.find({}).map { |d| 
   d["doc"]["children"].select { |rh| 
      rh["genre"] == "female"
   }.map { |r| 
      r["name"]
   }
}.flatten.uniq
```

But I have millions of entries and takes a lot of time. Mongodb surely have a way to return this result natively.

Comment: You should actuall try to define [named scopes](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#scoping) in your models.

Comment: I am not using mongoid. I am using `mongo` gem to connect directly to mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything about the socket timeout you got, but this query:

```
collection.find({"children" => {"genre" => "female"}})
```

does not give what you expect. It checks for exact equality between the children field and the given hash. A correct way to execute this query is:

```
collection.find("children.genre" => "female")
```

But it still finds all parents that have at least one female child. Male children of these parents are also included in this view and you have to filter them after getting the result.

Alternatively, you can do the whole selection with aggregate():

```
collection.aggregate([
  {:$unwind => '$children'},
  {:$match => {'children.genre' => 'female'}},
  {:$group => {_id: '$children'}}
]).map { |c| c[:_id] }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the query will take long time you can try to change the socket timeout connection on mongo driver and the https: //github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/socket/tcp.rb and the mongo query timeout option http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/ , or try to use the skip() and limit options of the query.